# Not seeing any Fields for a Y-Axis aggregation in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have grok filter for apache logs as follows :

```
if [type] == "apachelogs" {
    grok {
      break_on_match => false
      match => { "message" => "\[%{HTTPDATE:apachetime}\]%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:verb}%{SPACE}/%{NOTSPACE:ApacheRequested}" }
match=> { "message" => "\*\*%{NUMBER:seconds}/%{NUMBER:microseconds}" }

       add_tag => "%{apachetime}"
       add_tag => "%{verb}"
       add_tag => "%{ApacheRequested}"
       add_tag => "%{seconds}"
       add_tag => "%{microseconds}"
```

I want to create a visualisation in kibana for search type="apachelogs". O am using filebeat.So my search query is

```
filebeat*type="apachelogs"
```

I want ***apachetime*** in X-axis and ***microseconds*** in Y-axis.But in Y
-axis, I am not getting any fields except default ones (sum,count,aggregation).

Please help.I dont know what I am doing wrong.